# Vector are not showing at all after enabling & using Vector Drawable Library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to implement the Vector Drawable Library. I updated my code as per below but I ran into a new problem. Now the images/vector ***are not showing at all***.

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kanudo.ten"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
}
```

**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_note_outlines"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a miss...

For working it require to use `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>` instead of `<ImageView>`

OR/AND

One must extend `MainActivity` from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`